# Python - How to check if a specific function is calling your current function, and use that in an if/else within the current function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below method that runs and executes a query returning ids:

```
def _get_ids_from_snowflake(self):
   sf_hook = SnowflakeHook(warehouse)

   logging.info(f'Query fetching ids...')

   sql = f"""
         SELECT simple_id, id FROM my_table;
         """

  logging.info(f'Query finished!')

  return sf_hook.execute_query(queries=sql, fetch_all=True)
```

now I'm wondering if there's a way to make the sql query to be more dynamic within this method and split it out into 4 different queries with an if statement, that if my other method `get_response_2021` is calling `_get_ids_from_snowflake` it uses the sql1 statement:

```
sql1 = f"""
             SELECT simple_id, id FROM my_table where YEAR(id_date) = 2021;
             """
```

method `get_response_2022` is calling `_get_ids_from_snowflake` it uses the sql2 statement:

```
sql2 =  f"""
                 SELECT simple_id, id FROM my_table where YEAR(id_date) = 2022;
                 """
```

Also, if this isn't possible or doesn't make sense please tell me why I'd like to understand.

Comment: Why not make it a `def get_response(year, ...):` instead, and pass in the appropriate year?  Also, it's not clear how `_get_ids_from_snowflake` relates to `get_response` from the code you have provided, please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using the `inspect` module, but it is not the ideal or recommended approach.

You are better off using a parameter for the method which will work as a filler for the query itself, then each calling function can pass a different filler as an argument.

For example:

```
def _get_ids_from_snowflake(self, year=None):
  sf_hook = SnowflakeHook(warehouse)

  if year:
    sql = f"SELECT simple_id, id FROM my_table where YEAR(id_date) = {year};"
  else:
    sql = "SELECT simple_id, id FROM my_table;"

  logging.info('Query fetching ids...')
  logging.info('Query finished!')
  return sf_hook.execute_query(queries=sql, fetch_all=True)
```

then each of the calling functions can look something like this:

```
def get_response_2021(self):
    self._get_ids_from_snowflake(year='2021')

def get_response_2022(self):
    self._get_ids_from_snowflake(year='2022')
```

Just in case you need to do it the way you described this would be an example:

```
import inspect

class Klass:
    def _get_ids_from_snowflake(self):
        frame = inspect.stack()[1]
        print(frame.function)  # prints function name of the caller

        if frame.function == "get_response_2022":
           sql = f"SELECT simple_id, id FROM my_table where YEAR(id_date) = 2022;"

        elif frame.function == "get_response_2021":
            ...
        ...
        ...

        logging.info('Query fetching ids...')
        logging.info('Query finished!')
        return sf_hook.execute_query(queries=sql, fetch_all=True)


    def get_response_2021(self):
        self._get_ids_from_snowflake()  # prints get_response_2021

    def get_response_2022(self):
        self._get_ids_from_snowflake()  # prints get_response_2022

a = Klass()
a.get_response_2021()
a.get_response_2022()
```